# Media Queries Sizes

Tags: html, css, mobile, media

When writing media queries for smaller devices coming from a computer-first approach rather a mobile first approach such as for cell phones and ipads, what are good ranges of width for smartphone size and Ipad size?

```
@media screen and (min-width: _____) and (max-width: _____)
{
   code
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Oh, that's perfect! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post it as the answer for everyone else. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Media queries change all the time based on new devices and screens. It really depends on what you're trying to target.

But here's a great resource that can make like a little simpler

[www.css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices](http://www.css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices)

Cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

computers/laptops usually begin at 1200px, so when designing a website try to have your main container have a max width of 1199px so it will work on all computers and laptops.

ipad horizontal is 1024px,
ipad vertical is 768px.

cellphones will max out at 500px,
iphone 6+ is 414px,
iphone 6 is 375px,
iphone 5 and below is 320px.

androids range from 320px-500px.